# Does electric charge $e$ become complex at some scale $\mu$?

Tags: charge, quantum-electrodynamics, renormalization, singularities, regularization

\begin{equation}
\mu \frac{\partial{e}}{\partial \mu }=\frac{{e}^3}{12\pi^2}=\beta({e})\end{equation}
This is the equation for beta function in quantum electrodynamics, it tells us about how coupling constant scales with the scale $\mu$.
The solution to this equation is
\begin{equation}
{e}^2(\mu)=\frac{{e}^2(\mu_0)}{1-\frac{{e}^2(\mu_0)}{6\pi^2}\ln\frac{\mu}{\mu_0}} .  
\end{equation}
From this equation it is clear that running coupling constant ${e}$ increases with increasing scale (i.e., with $\mu$). This equation  has a pole at
\begin{equation}
\mu=\mu_0\exp\Bigg(\frac{6\pi^2}{{e}^2(\mu_0)}\Bigg).
\end{equation} and this singularity is called Landau singularity.
I refer these things from QFT by Ryder.

My question is for
$\mu \gg \mu_0\exp\Bigg(\frac{6\pi^2}{e^2(\mu_0)}\Bigg),$  ${e}^2(\mu)$ appears to be negative and hence $e$ to be complex, is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This equation results from the one-loop calculations. As such it is only valid for small values of $e(\mu)$. All it can really tell us is that the effective charge becomes larger at high energies for a while. But once the effective charge becomes big enough you need to go to higher order in the calculations and the effective charge evolution changes. Or worse, the theory becomes non-perturbative and you can't even rely on a finite number of diagrams to tell you the evolution. So even the existence of the pole is suspect, let alone any behavior at energies beyond the pole.